# p:command inside carousel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Why below works:

```
<h:form id="form1">
<p:carousel id="carousel" value="#{galleriaBean.paths_tn}" var="img" itemStyle="width: 200px">
<p:graphicImage value="#{img}"/>
</p:carousel>

<p:commandLink id="here" value="click me" update="hello11" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="hello!!!" target="#{galleriaBean.selected}"/>
</p:commandLink>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
<h:outputText id="hello11" value="#{galleriaBean.selected}"/>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

But moving the commandLink into the carousel, it doesn't work? *setPropertyActionListener* does not even set the variable in the bean.

@RequestScoped CDI Bean.

```
<p:carousel id="carousel" value="#{galleriaBean.paths_tn}" var="img" itemStyle="width: 200px">
<p:graphicImage value="#{img}"/>
<p:commandLink id="here" value="click me" update=":form1:hello11" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{img}" target="#{galleriaBean.selected}"/>
</p:commandLink>
</p:carousel>
```

Comment: What is scope of your backing bean?

Comment: Try @ViewScope and see what's happening.

Comment: Yes that fixed it... Used @SessionScoped please answer why this happens

Comment: Since you're using CDI, it would be better to use `@ViewScoped` from MyFaces CODI or stop using `@RequestScoped` from CDI and move it to `@ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.bean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show second version of your code (when you put `p:commandLink` inside `p:carousel`), but I suppose that you putted some property of backing bean inside `value` attribute of `p:commandLink`. You must be aware that AJAX request is also request, so you request scoped bean is recreated in each AJAX request. To preserve state of property, which you are using for `f:setPropertyActionListener` you must make your bean at least view scoped, or somehow retain state in `@PostConstructor` method. If you can use view scoped bean, that should be done.

Comment: On the second version code the funny thing is that it does not call the setter method on @RequestScoped bean.. that's weird. It does get created and destroyed though.